# how to make the screen blank when user is trying to take the screenshot of the website?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this feature in websites like Udemy , where in the best seller courses, if you try to take screenshot , they make the screen blank in this way .

I tried all possible ways of taking the screenshot like
*windows + prt src*, *windows + shift + s* ,*snipping tool*, but each one of this took the blank image as screenshot, how to implement this in a MERN stack website?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i prevent from printscreen of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427286/how-do-i-prevent-from-printscreen-of-my-webpage)

Comment: no ,it doesnt, i have seen it implemented in many websites like Udemy, Coding ninjas, even in netflix and prime too

Answer (score 1):

That feature is basically called DRM. So any DRM enabled content is protected by the browser (depends on the browser capabilities) itself from taking captured yet it is not 100% safe. You can read more from the topics below;

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252605325
https://www.reddit.com/r/Troubleshooting/comments/m74eis/cant_take_screenshots_of_a_udemy_course_video_in/

Edit After the comment;
Enabling DRM is related on what video player component you use. Considering you are able to use jwPlayer you can follow the documentation here;
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-enable-drm-through-the-web-player

Comment: how to make the DRM enabled content on a MERN stack website? is there any code? or how to implement that?

Comment: i didnt downvote, but i want to use this for the whole website, not only for a video player .how to do that? ,becasue i will be using the content as images, and there are like 10-20 images which would be on each page

Comment: is it possible to make the screen blank? when taking screenshots for images?

Comment: This answer is right. Not sure, why folks have down voted it. Udemy, netflix and other services stream DRM. Leveraging DRM features is how they prevent screenshot. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65155110/9366180