# How to stop page from being screen shared

Tags: javascript, websecurity, screensharing

I don't want a certain page of our website to be able to be screen shared in a meeting, how can I block screensharing of a page and replace it with a blank screen?

I know services like Paramount+ do it.
All I want to do is show a blank screenshare page whilst on the page to prevent an infinite loop

Comment: you can not even if nexflix think they can, if you disable gpu aceleration you can share it.

Comment: This is almost impossible to achieve. Even if you have complete control over your whole software stack (like Apple), there are still going to be ways (jailbreak) to circumvent security measures in place. And even if you could, what prevents a user from filming their sreen?

Comment: [Stack Overflow: How does Netflix prevent users from taking screenshots of chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63175756/how-does-netflix-prevent-users-from-taking-screenshots-of-chrome-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot block a page from being screenshared (by using JavaScript since I've noticed it's in the tags).

Comment: Is there a CORS policy that can do it, as services like Paramount+ prevent recording/screen sharing